# Suppose the heights of a population of $3,000$ adult penguins are approximately normally distributed with a mean of $65$ cm and ...

Tags: normal-distribution

I would like to check myself if following my answer is correct: let us consider following problem:

Suppose the heights of a population of $3,000$ adult penguins are approximately normally distributed  with a mean of $65$ centimeters and a standard deviation of $5$ centimeters.

(a) Approximately how many of the adult penguins are between $65$ centimeters and $75$ centimeters 
tall?

(b) If an adult penguin is chosen at random from the population, approximately what is the  probability that the penguin’s height will be less than $60$ centimeters? Give your answer to the nearest 0.05.

so as i know approximately $68$ or $2/3$ fall  in the interval of $[\mu-\sigma,\mu+\sigma]$,approximately $96$ fall between $[\mu-2*\sigma,\mu+2*\sigma]$

and  approximately $99$% fall between

$[\mu-3*\sigma,\mu+3*\sigma]$

now  we are asked between $75$ and $65$,which is equal

$[\mu-2*\sigma,\mu+2*\sigma]$

this range,but in this case it is second half range,in this range  it would be half of or $48$%,which means that  number of penguins would be $3000*0.48=1440$ penguins would be,am i correct?

on (b), less then $60$ means that below $65-5$ or below $[\mu-\sigma]$ or $16$ percent would be fall in this interval,am i correct?please help me

Comment: I think everything looks good.

Comment: only one thing which i did not understand is that,instead of $0.16$,there is $0.15$   in answers

Comment: maybe because it is less then $60$,itself $60$ or $1$ % is not counted?

Comment: For the first, $41432$ is closer to what is given by the tables. The $68\%$ you used is somewhat imprecise. For the second, they rounded to the nearest $.05$. That is what the question asked for. Your $16\%$ is closer to the truth.

Comment: No, regardless of whether the question is asking for $<60$ or $\le 60$, the answer is the same. However, I see the reason: they ask you to round to the nearest 0.05

Comment: could you explain it more detail?is both correct or?

Comment: i got exactly $16$ percent,how could i round?

Comment: @giorgi what is 0.16 rounded to the nearest 0.05?

Comment: itself $0.16$,it is not like $0.155$ right?we have exactly $0.16$

Comment: could you post as answer?please with example,it is very important for me

Comment: i will post it as a  question

Comment: @giorgi I think you are thinking of "rounding to the nearest 0.01" when they are asking you to "round to the nearest 0.05"

Answer (score 0):

For rounding 16% to the nearest 0.05 percent you should do the following calculations:
First divide 16% by 0.05: (16%/0.05) = 3.2. Then, round 3.2 to the nearest point = 3.
Now, you should multiply 3 to 0.05 = 0.15.

Good Luck